# Как изменять цвет разных частей персонажа?

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Я новичок в Unity и C#.
В игре Geometry Dash есть система смены цвета скина. Там можно поменять цвет одной части персонажа, а потом другой части. Я долго искал информацию - не нашёл, пытался сам придумать - не придумал.
На скрине игра Geometry Dash. Снизу две полоски цветов, меняющие цвета определённых частей скина.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать в Unity и в скрипте?
[image]

Comment: Вы не подумайте! Я не делаю клон этой игры! У меня просто похожая смена скина.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как один из вариантов - заливка кислотным цветом в графическом редакторе и последующая замена цвета програмно на необходимый тебе цвет. На основе даного принципа лежит работа с гринскринами в видео. Если нужны тени на обьекте - тень добавляется отдельной текстурой с альфаканалом. Сложно и не факт что рентабельно.

Как второй вариант - хранить текстуры всех необходимых цветов. Приложение будет занимать больше места, но улучшится быстродействие. В этом случае наверняка нужно все делать в одном большом файле(но в таком случае понадобится больше оперативки)

Вариант 3 (лично я за этот вариант)  - написание шейдера с возможностью замены с выбранного цвета на другой. Без знаний языка шейдера это можно сделать через шейдерграф.